# createBitmap --- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be < bitmap.width()

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting error while taking screenshot and create bitmap with cropping picture

below is my code

```
    View v1 = mKittyBGLayer.getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap source = v1.getDrawingCache();
    int width = source.getWidth();
    int height = source.getHeight();
    System.out.println("vListView : -"+vListView.getWidth());
    System.out.println("hListView : -"+hListView.getHeight());
    System.out.println("Width : -"+width);
    System.out.println("Height : -"+height);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, vListView.getWidth(), 0, width, height - hListView.getHeight());
```

my logcat is

```
        11-01 11:00:31.419: I/System.out(1658): vListView :- 60
        11-01 11:00:31.429: I/System.out(1658): hListView :- 60
        11-01 11:00:31.429: I/System.out(1658): Width :- 480
        11-01 11:00:31.429: I/System.out(1658): Height :- 320
        11-01 11:00:31.429: D/AndroidRuntime(1658): Shutting down VM
        11-01 11:00:31.429: W/dalvikvm(1658): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception  (group=0x40018560)
        11-01 11:00:31.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        11-01 11:00:31.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1658): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width  must be <= bitmap.width()
        11-01 11:00:31.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:410)
        11-01 11:00:31.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:383)
        11-01 11:00:31.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at com.appsehs.android.CUTECRAZYKITTENDRESSUPGAME.PhotoSortrActivity.takeScreenShot(PhotoSortrActivity.java:247)
        11-01 11:00:31.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at com.appsehs.android.CUTECRAZYKITTENDRESSUPGAME.PhotoSortrActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(PhotoSortrActivity.java:274)
        11-01 11:00:31.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205)
```

Here you can see that x < bitmap.getWidth mean 60 < 480

although i am getting error

Comment: on which statement u r getting the error?

Comment: bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, vListView.getWidth(), 0, width, height - hListView.getHeight());

Comment: if i do bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, width, height - hListView.getHeight()); it will work

Comment: ok @Siddhpura ur problem is that ur  vListView.getWidth() gives the width that is more than the width of ur bitmap so it throws the error.  get my point.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, not `x must be < bitmap.width()`. It says `x + width  must be <= bitmap.width()`.

You are creating a `Bitmap` like so:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 60, 0, 480, 260); // 320 - 60 = 260
```

Basically, you are drawing from `x = 60, y = 0` to `x = 480 + 60, y = 260` on a `Bitmap` which is only 480x320. Obviously, this is not possible, since your `x` coordinate is off the `Bitmap`.

It's hard to tell you how to fix this without knowing your exact use case. Basically, your `source` image has to fit within `{ x1: x, x2: x + width, y1: y, y2: y + height }`.

If you only want to draw from the 60th pixel onward, then you need to do this:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(source, vListView.getWidth(), 0, width - vListView.getWidth(), height - hListView.getHeight());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric, can you tell me how did you get this? i have read doc but can not find this! Eric i want to crop image from left side! please can you tell me how can i do this?

Comment: I am having an issue with my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347431/app-is-fc-if-the-user-presses-too-much-to-left-or-right

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0,
        sourceBitmap.getWidth() - 1, sourceBitmap.getHeight() - 1);
```

Like in lists, it starts from 0, so width must be bitmap width - 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are get image from drawable then add it into drawable-nodpi folder.

I have same issue. Now, working perfactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be < bitmap.width()

This is system crash on version 6.0.1 on Samsungs. At this moment I couldn't find cause.