# IllegalArgumentException in createBitmap method

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that picks the colour code of the image from gallery. The app is crashing with the error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

The crash is from this part of the method:

```
int i = paramBitmap.getWidth();
int j = paramBitmap.getHeight();
float f1 = paramInt2 / i;
float f2 = paramInt1 / j;
Matrix localMatrix = new Matrix();
if (i > j) {
    localMatrix.postRotate(90.0F);
}
f1 = Math.min(paramInt2/i, paramInt1/j);
f2 = Math.min(paramInt1/i, paramInt2/j);
localMatrix.postScale(f1, f2);
return Bitmap.createBitmap(paramBitmap, 0, 0, i, j, localMatrix, true); // Crashes here
```

What can be the reason for the crash? Please give your valuable inputs.

Comment: @kalyanpvs if it is zero then it will crash on calculating f1.

Comment: From the log, I can see: i=3263 j=2447. So they're not zero.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yes,you are right..but from the exception it is saying width and height must not be zero..

Comment: @webgenius post your complete log and and some more code of your bitmap loading..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
float f1 = newHeight / i;
float f2 = newWidth / j;
```

The precision of int `newWidth` and `newHeight` is less than `float` so when you calculate it, it will return 0. So instead of having a `parameter int` change it to `parameter float` to compute as floating point number instead of integer.

**sample**

```
private Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, float newHeight, float newWidth)
{
    int i = bm.getWidth();
    int j = bm.getHeight();
    float f1 = newHeight / i;
    float f2 = newWidth / j;
    Matrix localMatrix = new Matrix();
    if (i > j) {
        localMatrix.postRotate(90.0F);
    }
    f1 = Math.min(newHeight/i, newWidth/j);
    f2 = Math.min(newHeight/i, newWidth/j);
    localMatrix.postScale(f1, f2);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, i, j, localMatrix, true); // Crashes here
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. From the logs, I see: paramInt1=720 paramInt2=1280 i=3264 j=2448 f1=0.0 f2=0.0. Debugging further on this.

Comment: @webgenius change it to float. to fix it

Comment: I type-casted the int to float in the function calling part, and there is no crash now.  Thanks for the quick help. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Not x must be < bitmap.width(). It says x + width must be <= bitmap.width()

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171509/createbitmap-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-x-must-be-bitmap-width)