# Glide transformation not working

Tags: android, bitmap, android-glide

I want to crop a bitmap  from the top using a glide transformation, I have the following code:

```
public class TopCropTransformation extends BitmapTransformation {

    public TopCropTransformation(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TopCropTransformation(BitmapPool bitmapPool) {
        super(bitmapPool);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(toTransform, 0,0, outWidth, outHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return "TopCropTransformation";
    }
}
```

And I use transformation like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(user.getImageUrl())
.error(R.drawable.missingprofile)
.transform(new TopCropTransformation(context))
.into(holder.image);
```

And glide displays the error image. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: I've just found this exception "x + width must be <= bitmap.width()"

Comment: look @ this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/13171571/5255006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly solved using

```
@Override
protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {

    float heightRatio = (float)toTransform.getHeight() / (float)toTransform.getWidth();
    int newHeight = (int) (heightRatio * outWidth);
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(toTransform, outWidth, newHeight, false);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0,0, outWidth, outHeight);
}
```